# What is the best way to enable more than one network interface in a preseed (trusty)?

Tags: networking, 14.04, maas, preseed

I need to enable both network interfaces on nodes that I deploy using MAAS.  What is the recommended way to do that.  Right now, only a single interface (eth0) is getting enabled.  Do I modify the preseed file?  If so, is there a directive to enable it, or does it have to be some kind of post-install script?  I just need the interface enabled for DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

As long as i know, it is not possible to do this directly in the preseed file. The only way to activate an additional interface is by running a post-install script rewriting your /etc/network/interfaces file. The way to go is to use the 'd-i preseed/late_command' section in the preseed and there somehow download a script, make it runable and then run the script to set up your network.
I tried this for a couple of hours but did not succeed, it seems like even if your post install script modifies your /etc/network/interfaces, your modifications are somehow overwritten again, cf. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219851 . So i decided to just add machines modify then manually and the use them.

Comment: Hi, what do u mean modify manually? I have the same problem and it just bugs me to start the machine one by one and edit the file for each. thanks